# serializable columns on database should be of type "string" or "text"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, serialization

I need to create a column in my database that will contain serialized data. Should I pick a string column or a text column for that?

At first I would pick text because of the string limited size, but on a second thought, would it have an impact on performance? How should I decide in between string and text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're 100% certain that the serialized data will be less than the maximum size of a VARCHAR column in the database you should use text. Text columns also have limits depending on your database but in general should be sufficiently large.

If you're using Postgresql I'd suggest taking a look at HStore.

Comment: More on this theme: SQL tables are slow to write, and fast to read if you index. Indices can only use VARCHAR or smaller fields, not TEXT - except, sometimes, for the first 256 characters. So a TEXT field's performance hit won't hurt the slowest operation, which is data lookup. So use TEXT for serialized data.

Comment: Thanks for both answer and comment. Both very informative, for the HStore and the performance consideration.